# How do I reset my shell(?) password to delete GalliumOS?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, shell, chromium, chromebook

I am trying to delete GalliumOS off of my computer so I can have a ton more free space.

I have tried

1. Powerwashing
2. Toggleing in and out of dev mode
3. `sudo su`? I don't know what this does
4. `Ctrl + Alt + F2`
5. Chromebook Recovery Utility

I have an Acer Chromebook 14-SMB. It's hardware class is FALCO C2B-C4K-P7O. I am currently running Chrome OS version 76.0.3809.136.

I installed GalliumOS a few months ago to install minecraft but now I can't delete it. I have been searching for weeks and weeks and can't find a single thing. Can someone please help? All I need is a way to wipe EVERYTHING clean or a way to reset my shell/terminal/local-system-administrator thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to restore the default firmware and then run the Recovery Utility.

https://mrchromebox.tech/#faq under the heading: "UEFI is cool and all, but I'd like to revert to ChromeOS"